# Deserialization XmlArray not populating

Tags: c#, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a XML response from an API using C#.  I am not able to get the values of the `ItemList` element.  I am able to get the other elements besides the `ItemList`. A sample XML is below and Classes below that, and finally the serialize function.

**XML:**

```
<Root xmlns="http://whatever">
    <Child1>
        <ChildElement1>16f09999</ChildElement1>
    </Child1>
    <ItemList>
        <Element1>
        ...
        </Element1>

        <Item>
            <ItemElem1>12345567</ItemElem1>
            <ItemElem2>12356465784</ItemElem2>
           ...
            <ItemAttributes>
            ...
            </ItemAttributes>
        </Item>
        <Item>
        ...
        </Item>
    </ItemList>
</Root>

[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Root")]
public class ResponseClass
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Child1")]
    public OperationRequest OperationRequest { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("ItemList")]
    public ItemList ItemList { get; set; }
}
```

**Class:**

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(ElementName = "ItemList")]
public class ItemList
{
    [XmlArray("ItemList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Item", typeof(Item))]
    public Item item { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Element1")]
    public int Element1 { get; set; }

}
```

**Serializer:**

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResponseClass));

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
response = (ResponseClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

Comment: xmlarray in itemlist of responseclass....and some modifications like removing xmlroot from itemlist class...and in the item property removing the xmlarray...

Comment: not just that all i said above toghether...the element1 it will be created with the name you provided in ctor of xelement...

Comment: what if i wanted to get Element1 from XML as well as ItemList XMLArray?

Comment: i dont quite get what you mean??

Comment: well, i followed your suggestion from your first comment and put xmlarray in itemlist of responseclass.  however, the itemlist was intended to be a class that held a list and another element.  how could i get the xmlarray as well as another element?

Comment: ohhh sorry now i see, just remove the xmlroot from itemlist class and leave the rest as in the code above you presented and i think it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following. Since `ItemList/Item` is not a `XmlArray`, you need to define it as a simple `XmlElement`.

```
[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(ElementName = "Root", Namespace = "http://whatever")]
public class ResponseClass
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Child1")]
    public OperationRequest OperationRequest { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("ItemList")]
    public ItemList ItemList { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(ElementName = "ItemList", Namespace = "http://whatever")]
public class ItemList
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Item")]
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Element1")]
    public int Element1 { get; set; }
}
```